# Carregar stream de arquivo XML em XRRichText

Tags: c#, xml, stream, devexpress

Na minha aplicação, recebo do banco de dados um *array* de *bytes* de um arquivo **XML**. Com ele crio uma *stream*, mas quando tento carregá-la e inseri-la no `XRRichText`, nada acontece. Porém, se gravo a *stream* num arquivo do disco do computador do usuário, na hora de carregar o arquivo e inserir o conteúdo no componente, funciona perfeitamente. Mesmo assim, preciso que seja carregado através da stream, não de um arquivo.

O código abaixo funciona, mas não posso usá-lo por causa da criação de arquivos no computador do usuário:

```
RichEditDocumentServer server = new RichEditDocumentServer();

using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\temp\intro.xml"))
{
    file.Write(pDados.ByteXML, 0, pDados.ByteXML.Length);
} 
server.LoadDocument(@"C:\temp\intro.xml");

...

XRRichText x = (XRRichText)xrCont;
x.Rtf = server.RtfText;
```

O código abaixo não funciona, mas é como preciso fazer, através da *stream*, sem criar arquivos:

```
RichEditDocumentServer server = new RichEditDocumentServer();

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Write(pDados.ByteXML, 0, pDados.ByteXML.Length);
stream.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
server.LoadDocument(stream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml);

...

XRRichText x = (XRRichText)xrCont;
x.Rtf = server.RtfText;
```

Comment: pelo que eu entendi, você carrega o xml no `RichEditDocumentServer` e depois pega o RTF dele pra jogar no `XRRichText`... certo ?

Comment: Sim, @RovannLinhalis, mas imagino que isso não tenha nada a ver com o problema, já que funciona quando carrego o arquivo. O problema está na hora de carregar a stream...

Answer (score 1):

Use um binary writer pois o método `MemoryStream.Flush()` não realiza nenhuma ação([https://docs.microsoft.com/.../system.io.memorystream.flush](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.flush?view=netframework-4.7.2))

```
RichEditDocumentServer server = new RichEditDocumentServer();

//Cria um BinaryWriter sobre um MemoryStream usando usando a codificação UTF-8.
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());

//Envia os dados para MemoryStream.
writer.Write(pDados.ByteXML);
writer.Flush(); 


server.LoadDocument(writer.BaseStream , DocumentFormat.OpenXml);

...

XRRichText x = (XRRichText)xrCont;
x.Rtf = server.RtfText;
```